# How do I speedup X11 forwarding through SSH?

Tags: ssh, x11, xforwarding

I've been using X11 forwarding to "seamlessly" work on two machines at the same time and it's been working great. The one issue that I'm having is that the connection can be quite slow for some applications and I would like to speed it up. 
Since both machines are on my private home network I don't really care about the connection being secure, so my first approach was to either disable encryption or switching to a weaker cipher.

After a google search I found that I could get noticeably better performance by enabling trusted X11 forwarding (-Y) and compression (-C). However it appears that the weak but fast ciphers (arcfour and blowfish) have been removed from openssh a few versions ago.

So my questions are?

1. Is it possible to enable/install these ciphers?
2. If not, which of the currently available ciphers are the fastest?
3. Are there any other settings that can be adjusted to speedup the connection?

EDIT: The remote pc is running Ubuntu 20.04 and the local is running Pop!_OS 19.10 (Based on Ubuntu 19.10). Both use GDM3 as their window manager.

Comment: If both hosts are on a LAN and you don't care about security, you don't have to forward X through SSH in the first place. You could have your clients connect directly to the server over the LAN.

Comment: Nice suggestion, it didn't even pass through my mind. I'll look into it once I have some free time and maybe post an answer if I find some elegant way of doing this.

Comment: The Xserver option to look for is `-listen tcp`, but the hard part is finding where your distribution and display manager has hidden it. Add those two details to your post above.

Comment: `aes128-gcm@openssh.com` is the fastest cipher on modern x86-64 processors, but unless you have a network faster than gigabit, every secure encryption/MAC pair is fast enough.

Answer (score 1):

For an internal network protected from external access,
you can enable simple tcp connections to an Xserver. This used to be the default a long time ago, but no longer is, for security. If using gdm3 as display manager, you can edit file `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf` and add a line to the security stanza:

```
[security]
DisallowTCP=false
```

I don't know how to restart gdm3 so you may have to reboot to have this take effect. When you login you should see the `Xserver` running with option `-listen tcp`. Normally, this will be on display 0 which you will find listening on tcp port 6000. Ensure your firewall enables this port for tcp connections.

To check you can connect, you can temporarily allow all hosts to connect without authorization:

```
xhost +
```

On the client, run an X11 application with the display set to the remote server, eg (assuming the server is called `remote`) `DISPLAY=remote:0 xlogo` or `xlogo -display remote:0`. If this works, on the server reverse that setting, with `xhost -`, and either use other more limiting `xhost` options, or copy the MIT magic cookie key from the server's `~/.Xauthority` file. To do this, on the server run

```
xauth list
```

and choose the line that has the server's name, e.g.

```
remote/unix:0  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  653dc9bd80294684b4944f2babf2fd0c
```

(There may be more lines, ensure you choose the right one).
On the client, enter this key to the local authority file (using the name:display without the `/unix` since it is over tcp):

```
xauth add remote:0  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  2ac06b3b50200461378d0b8622f6d9f6
```

You should now be able to run applications again, just setting the display.